# how to import a .sql file using php function

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I am using Xampp server and I am trying to import a table into my database which is not working.  here is my code:

```
$mysqlDatabaseName ='postcodes';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
$mysqlImportFilename ='http://localhost/import_tbl/postcode_withLatlang.sql';

$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;

//var_dump( file_exists('postcode_withLatlang.sql') );

$output = array();

 exec($command, $output, $worked);
print_r($output);
echo $worked;

// test whether they are imported successfully or not
switch ($worked) {
 case 0:
        echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
 }
```

please help me

Comment: Pretty sure you cant use a remote address, for import.. so try removing `http://localhost` and fix it so it's a relative/absolute path.

Comment: I  removed http://localhost from file name, but still not work

Comment: Could be a few things, are you sure the path is correct? Did you add DROP TABLE IF EXISTS on exporting that database, else its going to bork out on import.

Comment: its not showing or generating anything...just spinning

Comment: whats spinning?

Comment: let me show you my sql file

Comment: '**DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `postcode`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `postcode` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,**'

Comment: when i press enter, the page is just loading, like its generating something

Comment: instead of pressing enter and being here, you could try to debug your code, add logging, exception handling, error handling, and come back here with real information.

Comment: its been two days now...i tried every single thing what ever you said ....but its not generating a table and not returning anything

Comment: @surma, well how big is this dump?  It's usually best to not run long running tasks in a web script.   Try running it through cli when you're debugging.

Comment: i m not inserting any data...just trying to import only one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now!
Firstly, it didn't work in local server and secondly, instead of **exec()** function I used the **system()** function and finally, it generates a table in my database. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
`$mysqlImportFilename ='http://localhost/import_tbl/postcode_withLatlang.sql';`
```

to

```
`$mysqlImportFilename ='postcode_withLatlang.sql';`,
```

then put your php-script file in the folder with .sql file and run it from that folder.

Comment: its not showing or generating anything...just spinning